# Dynamically add job to a Prometheus configuration

Tags: prometheus

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'dummy1'
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - targets.json
```

But in the case where I want to add a dynamic list of jobs, like dummy2, dummy3, etc. what would be the approach there? To add multiple targets for a job, file_sd_configs can be used. Is there any similar approach that is possible to add a dynamic job?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be supported (at the moment?). At least until multi-config files is supported.

What worked for me is to use Ansible to maintain the config file (add/remove jobs via blockinfile) and reload the service by sending a SIGHUP (as suggested there: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2041).

As an example, here is the Ansible task:

```
- name: Append new job
  notify: Reload Prometheus
  blockinfile:
    path: /home/prometheus/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK - My new job"
    block: |
      # Must be 2-space indented
        - job_name: "my job"
          file_sd_configs:
            - files:
              - "/home/prometheus/prometheus/my_group_of_servers.yml"
          metrics_path: "/my_metrics"
```

Here's the handler:

```
- name: Reload Prometheus
  systemd:
    name: prometheus
    state: reloaded
```

You also need to add reload support to systemd service file:

```
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
```

Hope that helps.